# When using Windows threads, can I specify a buffer to use for a thread's stack, similar to pthread_attr_setstack()?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, pthreads

pthreads allows the user to provide a chunk of memory to use for a thread stack:

```
size_t stack_size = 1024*1024*4;
void *stack = malloc( stack_size );
pthread_attr_t attributes;
pthread_attr_init( &attributes );
pthread_attr_setstack( &attributes, stack, stack_size );
pthread_t thread_id;
pthread_create( &thread_id, &attributes, worker_function, NULL
```

Do Windows threads provide similar functionality? The second parameter to [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) allows one to specify the minimum size of the stack, but I can't see a way to specify the address of a buffer to use.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the answer is "No".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not specify memory for stack as Jerry Coffin mention in comment, all you can specify is size of stack as second parameter to [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686774%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).