# Can I create a Thread with its stack at a specific address?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi, memory

I am experimenting a little and wondered whether it would be possible to create a thread with its stack at a specific address which I would supply, or at least let thread stacks only spawn within some (huge) virtual memory region I can specify.

The reason I am interested in this is that I'd like to copy the whole stack over to a remote process at some point and need pointers to stay intact, and for thread stacks to not collide.

It might not be the best/safest way of doing that, I know, but it's just a little hobby project. If you know how to do this on Linux, I'm interested in that too.

Comment: Hmmm... you do know that system managed memory (such as the stack) moves and that your pointer might not be valid by the end of the thread's lifetime, right? Also, you are aware that all the memory in the stack will be released and recycled the moment the thread exits (so none of it will be valid and another process might be using it by the time you get it)... right?

Comment: Too bad you're not on POSIX/Unix/Linux/WhateverBSD, you could have used [pthread_attr_setstackaddr(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstackaddr)...

Comment: @Myst System can't and doesn't move the stack. If it did all pointers would be invalid. Objects have the same address for their entire life.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It *can* move physical pages, but as the process only notices virtual ones, I think that doesn't counts a lot...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I'm fairly certain that I read that memory is moved around when I was researching something on Linux and I recall someone asked about pointers being preserved, but it could be that the discussion was part of a mistake someone made... I'm sorry if I got it wrong.

Comment: @Kemy That's the point of virtual memory. The system can move it physically, even on to disk. But the addresses are not moved

Comment: @Myst Physical backing can change. The addresses do not. Read about virtual memory.

Comment: @Myst: You got it wrong. I have read Linux's sources, and surely it doesn't do that. *Physical* pages *do* get moved sometimes (read about paging), but *virtual* pages, that is, the ones that the process looks at, don't. The OS can't relocate pointers because it doesn't know what parts of memory contain pointers, what registers are treated as pointers, or even if the application has already manipulated/encrypted/sent-through-a-socket addresses somehow!

Comment: Even **if** you could assign a specific address to your stack, that wouldn't get you any closer to whatever you are trying to solve. Values on the stack could be anything: Screen coordinates, GDI object handles, file pointers, kernel object handles, pointers to dynamically allocated objects, and so on. Copying this data to a foreign process renders it unusable.

Comment: So after looking up `pthread_attr_setstack`, turns out the answer to my question is [no for windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992231/when-using-windows-threads-can-i-specify-a-buffer-to-use-for-a-threads-stack), and yes for Unix. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: LOL, moving virtual memory, stacks etc, around.  None of my apps would run for more than a few ms:)

Comment: @KemyLand and DavidHeffernan - thank you for correcting my knowledge.

Comment: To copy the whole stack you don't need to SET a stack location, you need to FIND out a stack location. Or I missed something?

Comment: @KonstantinL well if I copy it and paste it into a different process, I need to paste it at the same location. And there is the small possibility of two stacks overlapping.

Comment: @snowflake Do you fully control the target process? Could you use VirtualAlloc( MEM_RESERVE )?

Comment: @KonstantinL Yes, I was planning to do that anyway in what I was writing. What doynax commented on my answer below is something I'm considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compiling what the comments said.

- [For windows, the answer is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992231/when-using-windows-threads-can-i-specify-a-buffer-to-use-for-a-threads-stack)
- For Unix (posix), the answer is [`pthread_attr_setstack`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setstack). (Also see the above link)

Comment: You can certainly use a buffer of your choosing as the stack even under Windows, just reserve a minimal buffer during thread creation and restore the original stack at exit or invoke `ExitThread`. Just use a small assembly wrapper to switch out the stack pointer and call back to C on a forged stack frame. You will need to handle guard pages/overflow checking manually via structure exception, and there are platform-specific subtleties (exception unwinding records, the dual-stack Itanium, alignment requirements, etc). Plus a host of subtleties I've repressed since last attempting this.

Comment: Check out this [link from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/adjusting-thread-stack-address-to-improve-performance-on-intel-xeonr-processors) that deals with adjusting stack address on Xeon processors .. I don't see any `asm` specific to the Xeon so it might work on other x86 Windows platforms ..